# Interfacing with Uniswap/Pancakeswap locally

Tags: contract-development, uniswap, pancakeswap

I'm interacting with PancakeSwap for the first time, as I'm developing a token that interfaces with PancakeSwap. Ideally I'd like to iteratively test it without deploying to a live network.

Must I deploy to the main network/testnet, or am I able to test it locally (e.g. Hardhat network)? If the latter, how?